# Extract specific data from a text file and import it in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8.1

I have a .txt file with lot of information, but I only need the numbers from *Mean Absolute Error* and *Root Mean Squared Error*. How can I automate and extract the numbers and put them in a Excel table.

Any help is welcome. Command Line, Script, Java, Regular Expressions, Powershell ...
 I am using Windows 8.1

Hear is a small part of my .txt file:

```
#############################################################################################################
Recommendation Type: ClusterBasedRecommendation (Experiment 1) for User 1 based on 2 friends: 
     Friends: 9, 220
     Distance: normal
     distThreshold: 0.0 / support weight: 0.35 / relevance weight: 0.65
     Highest predicted rating: 0.87 / Lowest predicted rating: 0.0
     Mean Absolute Error: 0.1516666666666667 / Root Mean Squared Error: 0.1552149047825842
     Fetching friends: 16ms  / Computing distances: 0ms  / Filtering friends: 0ms  / Calculate Recommendations: 15ms  / Overall: 31ms 
    Kendall Tau : 
#############################################################################################################
#############################################################################################################
Recommendation Type: ClusterBasedRecommendation (Experiment 1) for User 2 based on 3 friends: 
     Friends: 22, 182, 310
     Distance: normal
     distThreshold: 0.0 / support weight: 0.35 / relevance weight: 0.65
     Highest predicted rating: 1.0 / Lowest predicted rating: 0.0
     Mean Absolute Error: 0.15166666666666664 / Root Mean Squared Error: 0.16581448804143878
     Fetching friends: 1ms  / Computing distances: 0ms  / Filtering friends: 0ms  / Calculate Recommendations: 0ms  / Overall: 1ms 
    Kendall Tau : 
#############################################################################################################
#############################################################################################################
Recommendation Type: ClusterBasedRecommendation (Experiment 1) for User 3 based on 2 friends: 
     Friends: 20, 98
     Distance: normal
     distThreshold: 0.0 / support weight: 0.35 / relevance weight: 0.65
     Highest predicted rating: 0.87 / Lowest predicted rating: 0.0
     Mean Absolute Error: 0.07 / Root Mean Squared Error: 0.07826237921249264
     Fetching friends: 0ms  / Computing distances: 0ms  / Filtering friends: 0ms  / Calculate Recommendations: 0ms  / Overall: 0ms 
    Kendall Tau : 
#############################################################################################################
#############################################################################################################
```

Comment: What have you done already? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You need just numbers, or numbers next to data from "Recommendation Type"?

Comment: Oh dear, what nonsense software produce output like this?

Comment: @Kamil it is a Java written program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution.

Instructions: paste your text into column A and run this VBA code.

```
Sub ParseData()

Dim counter As Long
counter = 2

For Each cell In Range("A1", Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))

    If Left(Trim(cell), 19) = "Mean Absolute Error" Then
        Cells(counter, 3) = Mid(cell, InStr(1, cell, ":") + 1, InStr(1, cell, "/") - InStr(1, cell, ":") - 1)

    End If

    If InStr(1, cell, "Root Mean Squared Error:") > 0 Then
        Cells(counter, 4) = (Mid(cell, InStr(1, cell, "Root Mean Squared Error:") + 25, 30))
    counter = counter + 1
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Warning: be aware of Excel decimal precision limitation, because it's cutting it off after 11 decimal points.

Comment: @Devid, Did it work out?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It worked after I tried a few times.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-programming solution...
Paste the text into a single column in Excel
**Auto-filter** - text that **contains** "Mean Absolute Error" and since the numbers you're looking for are in the same line you'll be left with only the info that you need
then you can use the *Convert text to column wizard* to diliminate to just the numbers.

It takes several manual steps, but if you don't need this automated then you should be done within a minute or two.